# How would I change the audio volume in this script? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

So I have a script used for playing random songs:
http://pastebin.com/G5JNFfY9

I'm not exactly sure how I could alter the volume, could anyone figure it out?
*(This script is in production on a project of mine: http://popsplit.us)*

**P.S.** Sorry I don't have that much detail, this is my first ever question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to show any relevant code directly in the question (note: we don't need to see the full array of 100+ files, two or three is enough to give the idea).

Comment: [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/volume)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Noted for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Use [the `volume` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/volume) on `audio` elements (inherited from the `media` element).

**Example Syntax:**

```
var audio = new Audio('/assets/music/1.mp3')

// later
audio.volume = 0.0 // muted
audio.volume = 0.5 // half strength
audio.volume = 1.0 // full strength
```

Comment: Glad to help! If you have time for an accept and/or upvote I would appreciate it! :)